# Casting float.MaxValue to Long throws exception?

Tags: c#, .net

Trying to get integer part of float.MaxValue but it is throwing error?

```
        long l = Convert.ToInt64(float.MaxValue);
        Console.WriteLine(l);
```

Error:
Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Comment: I just want the integer part of float.MaxValue either in int32 or int64.

Comment: thanks all, just curious about how float can be bigger then int32, both uses 32 bits.  float : 32 bit while int32: 32bit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maximum value of a [`float`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza(v=VS.100).aspx) is 3.4E+38, while the maximum value of a [`long`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk(v=VS.100).aspx) is 9.2E+18. Therefore, `float.MaxValue` will not fit into a `long`.

The [`Convert.ToInt64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9www74y.aspx) method throws an `OverflowException` when you specify a value that is greater than `Int64.MaxValue` or less than `Int64.MinValue`

If you just want to get the integer value of `float.MaxValue`, see the relevant answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040707/c-get-digits-from-float-variable). But note that even stripped of the floating point, the maximum value of a `float` will still not fit in the `long` data type.

**EDIT:** The reason that a `float` (a 32-bit value) has a higher maximum value than a `long` (a 64-bit value) is because of the way floating point numbers are internally represented by the computer. Floating point value types can hold wider ranges of values than can fixed-point and integer types, although this greater range is achieved at the expense of precision.

Answer (score 6):

Although a `float` is a smaller (4 byte) structure than a `long` (8 byte) is, it does have a wider *range*. (EDIT: In response to 'why', you might want to read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). Unlike most integral-types, their range doesn't equal 2 ^ Bits.)

```
float.MaxValue ~= 3.402823+e38
long.MaxValue ~= 9.223372+e18
```

Clearly, the integral part of `float.MaxValue` can't be represented as a `long`. (Never mind the fact that asking for this sort of precision with such a large, single-precision, floating-point number is normally completely meaningless).

Now, you could try using [**`System.Numerics.BigInteger`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) here (with the [appropriate constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268360.aspx)) if you really want to represent this with an integral type, but without further information I would seriously doubt you have a *real* need for integer arithmetic with such large numbers.

If all you need is to *display* the number in fixed-point notation, you can use the appropriate [format-specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#FFormatString):

```
//output: "340282300000000000000000000000000000000"
Console.WriteLine(float.MaxValue.ToString("F0"));
```

Comment: I just want the integer part of float.MaxValue either in int32 or int64

Comment: @Lalit: Yes but the problem is that the integer part of `float.MaxValue` > `long.MaxValue` so you can't fit it in even if you cut off the floating point.

Comment: float : 32 bit while long : 64 bit

Comment: is there any way to get integer part of float.MaxValue in any data type.

Answer (score 3):

In .Net 4 there is a new [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) type that could handle that size of number.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN about float conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk%28VS.71%29.aspx)

> Notice also that there is no implicit conversion from floating-point types to long.

Comment: this doesn't matter as he doesn't want to implicitly cast it. It's a problem with the respective MaxValues.

Comment: o,yes, it is a problem with MaxValues, not in conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the TryParse method on Int64. If it fails then just take the integral part of the float using:

Int64.Parse(s.Substring(s.IndexOf(".") + 1));