# Is Range of value depends upon Size of datatype?

Tags: c#, types

float have size of 4 bytes and long have size of 8 bytes.
So, size of float is smaller than size of long. but, range of float is greater than long.

Same case for decimal and double.

**Data Types**

```
  +----------+------------+----------------------+
  | Data Type|   Size     |        Range         |
  +----------+------------+----------------------+
  |  long    | 8 bytes    |-9.22e18 .. 9.22e18   |
  |  float   | 4 bytes    |-3.40e38 .. 3.40e38   |
  |  decimal | 16 bytes   |-7.92e28 .. 7.92e28   |
  |  double  | 8 bytes    |-1.80e308 .. 1.80e308 |
  +----------+------------+----------------------+
```

**Example:**

```
        decimal f = 10000000000000000000.0m;            //takes 16 bytes
        double d = 10000000000000000000000000000.0d;   //takes 8 bytes
```

So, double can hold greater value and takes less size than decimal.Why?

Comment: Also see the answers to a more contextualized version of the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232590/casting-float-maxvalue-to-long-throws-exception. Perhaps most importantly, read this document: http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because double has devoted more bits to the exponent than the decimal has.

Answer (score 0):

Because you loose some accuracy with double and float for larger values. Take a peek at the [IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) for the exact equations.

To put it very simply think of it like this. If I gave you 2 single digit numbers to represent a value you represent that number in a couple of ways...

If you simply followed the normal convention of writing numbers and your range would be 00 -> 99. However, you could choose to encode your two numbers in scientific notation, then your range would be 0 x 10^0 -> 9 x 10^9.

In the end both encoding represent the same number of possible values but the range on the later encoding is much greater.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your last sentence means. How can one have a larger range if they both represent the same number of possible values?

Comment: Because there are "gaps" in the latter encoding, but can encode exactly 100 values with each: (0 -> 99) in the first and in the second you can encode 0 -> 9 as n x 10^0 and then 10, 20, 30, 40... as n x 10^1 but you can't represent 11 -> 19 in this encoding. This is still a bit cryptic but I hope it's slightly more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, floating point numbers are approximations. They are not exact values as integers are. So what you gain in range on doubles, you pay in accuracy. The more operations you do on doubles (adding, subtracting,...) the more they lose their accuracy.  For most calculations, doubles are perfect but for monetary calculations you definitely want to use decimals.