# Why Convert.ToInt32("10.0") fails

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005

Not only in .NET, but such conversion fails even in SQL Server 2005...

Can anyone tell me why ?.

Wouldn't it be prudent to return just the integer part even in case of

```
    Convert.ToInt32("10.2")
```

Comment: I suggest removing the part about `"10.2"`, as clearly that is not an integer. The question in the title, about `"10.0"`, is the interesting one.

Comment: It's an interesting question but the error makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better fail than return some unexpected result. `10.0` and `10.2` are not integers. If you know that you will be dealing with floating point numbers use the corresponding data type:

```
float result = Convert.ToSingle("10.2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Also don't forget to take the culture into account when dealing with floating point numbers as the decimal separator might not always be `.`.

Comment: @The King, it just doesn't feel natural. I really don't understand why wouldn't you use the correct data type.

Comment: I'm not against using correct datatype.  I just got into a situation in SQL server where IsNumeric([InsCode]) returns true but conversion fails because of this.  Its pretty long story and hard to explain it here...  Its okay I converted to decimal before converting to int.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but consider another scenerio; consider parsing an SSN from this:  "000000123456789".    As a human, we can look at that and discern that the number has probably been padded (for whatever reason), but from a strictly objective sense, there's no good way to *know* how to pick 9 digits out of a string with more.  Similarly, there's no way to definitively convert a string with decimals to an int (even if it may seem obvious that those are just filler in certain specific cases).

Answer (score 6):

Others have explained why parsing "10.2" as 10 would be a bad idea. Now let's consider "10.0".

"10.0" is a string representation of a number which *can* have a fractional part - in other words, not an integer.

If you're parsing a value *as* an integer, you should be parsing an integer representation. "10.0" is almost certainly only *coincidentally* an integer... the data source isn't obviously a source of integers, so you shouldn't treat them as integers.

If you want the closest integer to a "real" number, you should parse it *as* a real number, and then round however you want to.

Think of it this way: choosing the right form of parsing is expressing a belief in the format of the input. The current behaviour is telling you that you're guessing badly.

Answer (score 2):

Because 10.2 is not an integer and it would be better that the programmer would be explicit about the loss of precision.

If this would work and not throw, there is a good chance that unintended loss of precision errors due to incorrect type assignments/conversions would occur.

Comment: @The King - You are asking the parsers to read your mind. As soon as the parser sees the `.` it fails since you have not provided a valid integer representation. If you mean to parse a floating point number, you should use the correct data type.

Comment: Another post is very similar: Extract decimal part from a floating point number in C - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040707/c-get-digits-from-float-variable

Answer (score 2):

Convert.ToInt32("10.0") is just call to Int32.Parse("10.0")
Which, in its turn equal to Number.ParseInt32("10.0", NumberStyles.Integer, NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(provider));

Most interesting part here is NumberStyles.Integer value. This is a composite numeber style, including AllowLeadingWhite, AllowTrailingWhite, and AllowLeadingSign styles. Mind that AllowDecimalPoint is not included in NumberStyles.Integer value. So, if string contains decimal point, we have format exception. Because decimal point is not allowed for parsing Int32.