# How to check whether a given string is Decimal or not in C#?

Tags: c#, decimal, tryparse

I have done this with string values like  `65.34, 65,45, 34.45`

Everything returns True ...

```
public void test()
{
   string value = "65" 0r "65.0" 0r "1,234.54";
   decimal number;

   if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out number))
      MessageBox.Show(value);
   else
      MessageBox.Show("Unable to parse '{0}'.", value);
 }
```

This all returns its a Decimal ..

```
         If I type "0.65" .. I need to show error and it i type "65" it has to be exectued.
```

Comment: "If I type 65 .. I need to show its an integer... if I type 65.0 then I have to show error"  Yet, your question is about parsing decimals...  I'm confused.  `65` and `65.0` are valid decimal values.

Comment: sir if i am typing .65 i have to show error. if i am typing 24.23  i dont have to show error.. how can i do that

Comment: You have not asked an answerable question.  It was asked of you to clarify your question--which might remove the downvotes. (Edit your question with clarification, don't put it in comments.)

Comment: It looks like you want to obtain the fractional digits from a floating point number, or at least verify that it isn't a whole number. Looks like a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040707/c-sharp-get-digits-from-float-variable

Comment: And do you want .65 to be invalid? Because it is lower than 1 or because it does not start with a 0? I'd accept .65 as a valid Decimal otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1.Use [Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811031/decimal-or-numeric-values-in-regular-expression-validation)

or

2.USe the following method to find the number of decimal places

```
 static decimal CountDigitsAfterDecimalPoint(decimal decimalNumber)
        {
            int[] bits = Decimal.GetBits(decimalNumber);
            int exponent = bits[3] >> 16;
            int result = exponent;
            long lowDecimal = bits[0] | (bits[1] >> 8);
            while ((lowDecimal % 10) == 0)
            {
                result--;
                lowDecimal /= 10;
            }

            return result;
        }
```