# Correct way for get fractional part double like int

Tags: c#, .net

I need get fractional part of double like int and only two numbers. My code

```
(int)Math.Floor(val * 100 - (int)val * 100)
```

but this can `(int)val * 100` may be out of range of int or long. Ok. 
If i try

```
(int)Math.Floor((val - (int)val) * 100)
```

Return value may be incorrect. For example:

```
double val = 56.9;
int retVal = (int)Math.Floor((val - (int)val) * 100);
// retVal = 89, because (val - (int)val) return 0.899999999675
```

How correct get fractional part of double like int?

Comment: means You want `899999999675` as int ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the decimal part from a double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038482/get-the-decimal-part-from-a-double)

Comment: To get around rounding errors you should use `decimal` if possible.

Comment: @Андрей check my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# get digits from float variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040707/c-sharp-get-digits-from-float-variable)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/55160793/11065582

Comment: check this [https://stackoverflow.com/q/55160793/11065582](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55160793/11065582)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this extensions method:

```
public static int GetFrac2Digits(this double d)
{
    var str = d.ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return int.Parse(str.Substring(str.IndexOf('.') + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
double val = 56.9;
double result=0;
int retVal = (int)Math.Floor((val - (int)val) * 100);
// retVal = 89, because (val - (int)val) return 0.899999999675
int FrctPart=result.ToString().Split('.')[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this maybe?

```
decimal d = (decimal)val;
int retVal = Math.Floor((d - Math.Floor(d)) * 100);
// 59.9 --> 90
// 123.456 --> 45
```

Comment: The `Math.Round()` function may alter the digits. I think is not the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`Math.Truncate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.truncate.aspx) instead of casting to `int`:

```
double val = 56.9;
int retVal = (int)Math.Round((val-Math.Truncate(val)) * 100);
// retVal is now 90
```