# How to split Double value in dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to assign two variables to integer and decimal parts on double.
how to do it?
[image]

Comment: check this it can help you a lot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848627/correct-way-for-get-fractional-part-double-like-int

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be

```
int x = abc.toInt()
int y = int.tryParse(abc.toString().split('.')[1]);
```

Comment: Error: A value of type 'double' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'

Comment: result should be int

Comment: i tried.  int x = abc.toInt();
    double y = abc - x; output is 1 and 0.399999999

Comment: int x = abc.toInt();
    int y = (abc - x).toInt(); result is 1 and 0

Comment: I updated my answer. I haven't found an easier way.

Answer (score 4):

```
final double abc = 1.4;
int a = int.parse(abc.toString().split(".")[0]);
int b = int.parse(abc.toString().split(".")[1]);
```

Try this out, it should work fine

Answer (score 1):

```
final abc = 1.4;
final numberValue = abc.floor();
final floatValue = abc - numberValue;
print(abc);
print(numberValue);
print(floatValue);
```